# Recursion and Yield return

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a method `HandleChildItems` which returns an `IEnumerable<object>`. This method in turn calls a method `GetChildItems`. In the `GetChildItems` method I make a recursive call to add the items to a list and then the `GetChildItems` method return a list back to the `HandleChildItems` method.

To return it as an `IEnumerable` I'm running a `foreach` loop on the list of items in `HandleChildItems` method with `yield return`.

But this seems to be taking more time as my xml file has more than 100 thousand entries.

Is there a way I can handle this while calling the recursive method itself?

```
private IEnumerable<object> HandleChildItems()
{ 
    var childItemslst = new List<Item>(); 
    childItemslst = GetChildItems(xmlnode);

    foreach (var item in childItemslst)
    {
        yield return item ;
    }
}

private List<Item> GetchildItems(XMLnodeList nodeList)
{
    List<Item> lstItem = new List<Item>();
    // Here I recursively call the method to add the items to list
    foreach (xmlnode xn in nodeList)
    {
        if (xn.childnodes.count > 0)
        {
            GetChildItems(xn.childnodes);
        }
        else
        {
            item = new Item
                   {
                       Code = "123",
                       Itemtext = "xyz"                            
                   };          
        }
        lstItem.add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least two alternatives which would be better than what you're doing now:

1. Build a single `List<T>` object recursively, by passing the object to the recursive method.
2. Don't build a `List<T>` object at all; instead, just recursively evaluate iterators.

Example of #1 (I did not bother to try to clean up any but the most obvious bugs/syntax errors in the original code):

```
private IEnumerable<object> HandleChildItems()
{ 
    var itemsList = new List<Item>(); 

    GetChildItems(xmlnode, itemsList);

    // IEnumerable<T> is covariant
    return itemsList;    
}

private void GetChildItems(XMLnodeList nodeList, List<Item> itemsList)
{
    // Here I recursively call the method to add the items to list
    foreach (xmlnode xn in nodeList)
    {
        if (xn.childnodes.count > 0)
        {
            GetChildItems(xn.childnodes, itemsList);
        }
        else
        {
            itemsList.Add(new Item { Code = "123", Itemtext = "xyz" });
        }
    }
}
```

Example of #2:

```
private IEnumerable<object> HandleChildItems()
{ 
    foreach (Item item in GetChildItems(xmlnode))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Item> GetChildItems(XMLnodeList nodeList)
{
    // Here I recursively call the method to add the items to list
    foreach (xmlnode xn in nodeList)
    {
        if (xn.childnodes.count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Item item in GetChildItems(xn.childnodes))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new Item { Code = "123", Itemtext = "xyz" };
        }
    }
}
```

Example #1 has the advantage that you create just one intermediate object, the `List<Item>` itself. But it does require that the entire list be stored in memory at once.

Example #2 creates a potentially large number of iterator method objects, one for each level of recursion. But this number is likely much smaller than the total number of `Item` objects you would have to create, and you do avoid having to store all those `Item` objects in memory all at once.

Comment: In example 2, `GetChildItems` should return `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<Item>`.

Answer (score 2):

A List<> is already an IEnumerable. You don't have to convert it.

citing the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx):

`public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
    IEnumerable`

And adding the sublists can be done by [List.AddRange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It seems to me that the real question here is how to avoid creating a large number of `List<Item>` objects. The above doesn't seem to me to address that.